# xsl:condition checking

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an input XML as below

```
<testing>
<subject ref="yes">
 <firstname>
    tom
 </firstname>
</subject>
<subject ref="no">
 <firstname>
    sam
</firstname>
</subject>
</testing>
```

I am expecting my output should be.

if the subject has ref as yes.  I will get the name value. Else if the ref (no) i won't get element

```
<testing>
<firstname>
   tom
</firstname>
</testing>
```

Please guide me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by building on top of the identity transform. Firstly, you would need a template to ignore **subject** elements with a @ref of 'no'

```
<xsl:template match="subject[@ref='no']" />
```

And for **subject** elements with a @ref of 'yes' you have another template to output just its children

```
<xsl:template match="subject[@ref='yes']">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

In fact, if @ref could only ever be 'yes' or 'no' you could simplify this template match to just `<xsl:template match="subject">` as this would match all elements which don't have a @ref of 'no'

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="subject[@ref='no']" />

   <xsl:template match="subject">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<testing>
<firstname> tom </firstname>
</testing>
```

Answer (score 1):

This short transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <testing><xsl:apply-templates/></testing>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="subject[@ref='yes']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="subject"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<testing>
    <subject ref="yes">
        <firstname>
         tom
     </firstname>
    </subject>
    <subject ref="no">
        <firstname>
         sam
     </firstname>
    </subject>
</testing>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<testing>
   <firstname>
         tom
     </firstname>
</testing>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<testing>
  <xsl:if test="testing/subject/@ref = 'yes'">
    <firstname>
      <xsl:value-of select="testing/subject/firstname" />
    </firstname>
  </xsl:if>
</testing>
```

I hope this should work in xslt

Comment: Hi @Ankur Ghelani, thank you very much for the reply but right now. I am using the same it was taking care only the if it is yes in ref but i want if my ref is no i don't want to display the element.  More over in test i we put as you given path expression error.

Comment: do you what to display `<testing>` or not if there is **no** in `ref`? also, you will have to put that one in loop, if you didn't then it would error, if that is the case then update, i'll update it.

Comment: what exactly i want is 

if my @ref="yes" in xml i want to display firstname else if my @ref="no" i don't to display the firstname.

Comment: this is what it is doing now.. but you will need to change accordingly it's path about xml  in `test` and in `select`, also, I have updated, little bit as well now, I have forgot to write yes in quot like `'yes'`